# Refund for a cancelled return ticket

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, kenya-airways

I bought a round ticket with Kenya Airways, and used the first ticket,
but the return flight was cancelled due to Covid-19.

the airline offered an open ticket that will be valid till June 2021, and that they can offer a refund only after that date.

I already booked another return flight, and have no need of the open ticket.

Is there any way for me to get the refund without waiting a year?
Can I dispute the charge with the credit card company?

Comment: What countries were you flying to and from? Or was this domestic travel within Kenya?

Comment: Return flight is from Bangkok to Dar Es Salaam

Comment: That's the billion-dollar question these days... Even when they are legally required to refund, airlines currently do all they can do avoid doing it. They just don't have the cash available. You could try disputing the charge with the credit card company, but it will probably depend how long ago you made the payment.

Comment: @jcaron US card issuers are required to address chargebacks brought up by the cardholder within 60 days of the charge appearing on the customer's statement. Card issuers are not prohibited, however, from entertaining chargebacks after the 60 day period. I have had some provisional success in May 2020 when I challenged charges posted and paid by me in September 2019.  I don't know what the rules or practice might be in other jurisdictions, or under other credit card issuer T&Cs.

Answer (score 2):

Legally, the airline owes you that money, and owes it to you *now*.

The problem is that nearly all airlines have significant cash flow problems, and therefore try to wiggle out of paying *any* cash if they can.
You can only call and nag them, maybe tell them that you plan to get a lawyer and sue them. Maybe they pay then, or maybe they sit it out - they will have to pay at the end, and they know that, but the later the better for them. They might even offer you double or triple the value of the ticket for flying in the next year - anything to avoid paying cash now.